# How do obtain a list of classes in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, class

I am developing an iOS app and would like to
obtain a list instance methods for classes in my xcode project.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want this for documentation purposes (rather than just while using XCode) you can run various programs over your code to extract the details and generate documentation in various formats.

One possibility is to use [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) (which is fairly intense to come up to speed on, but is very good at what it does).  A mini tutorial on this is shown in [Documenting objective-c with Doxygen part i](http://www.duckrowing.com/2010/03/18/documenting-objective-c-with-doxygen-part-i/), [Documenting objective-c with Doxygen part ii](http://www.duckrowing.com/2010/03/18/documenting-objective-c-with-doxygen-part-ii/) and [Using the doxygen helper in xcode 4](http://www.duckrowing.com/2011/05/14/using-the-doxygen-helper-in-xcode-4/)

This tutorial also mentions the Apple product [HeaderDoc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/HeaderDoc/intro/intro.html), and another 3rd party product (apparently no longer supported) [AutoDoc](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?AutoDoc), but the author prefers Doxygen (as do I)

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 3: *View* → *Smartgroups* → *Symbols*.
For Xcode 4 see [Browse to Project Symbols](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/Orientation/Orientation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009984-CH5-SW29).